# What is reductive deamination?

Tags: biochemistry, digestion

[This presentation on anaerobic digestion mentions (pg. 19)](https://www.dbfz.de/web/fileadmin/user_upload/Vortraege/BiogasWorld2014/18_Kovacs_ENG.pdf) two major pathways for the digestion of amino acids: Stickland reaction and reductive deamination. While I find some info on the former, what is reductive deamination? What is a representative reaction and what partners are needed?

Answer (score 2):

Amine is already a reduced state and therefore the reduction part is not of the amine. In chemical process of reductive deamination the arylamine is first converted to an intermediate, usually by sulphonylation of the amine nitrogen [[ref]](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jo010681w), which in turn is reduced.

$ArNH_2 + CH_3SO_2Cl \ \ \  _{\overrightarrow{pyridine}}\ \ \  ArNHSO_2CH_3 \ \ \  _{\overrightarrow{NaH+NH_2Cl}}  \ \ \ ArH$

Biochemical anaerobic reductive deamination is reported but not for amino acids (I couldn't find any). It is reported for anilines which probably proceeds via a carboxyl intermediate [[1](http://kops.ub.uni-konstanz.de/handle/urn%3anbn%3ade%3absz:352-opus-25611), [2](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1574-6968.2002.tb11149.x/pdf)].

[This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC252412/) article says that the non-classical amino acid $ornithine\ \ $ is converted to $\delta-aminovaleric acid\ \ $ via a $\ proline\ $ intermediate but no mechanism is described.

I don't think this answers your question completely; the best solution would be to ask the author of the presentation for the exact reference.